# Is there anyway to know which user is calling the WCF Ria service on server side, using silverlight on clientside?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Is there anyway to know which user is calling the WCF Ria service on server side? Client side is siverlight, user has to be authenticated first in order to use the system.

I need to know which user is actually calling the service in my current task, thanks, i searched a lot, but seems no good findings.

Answer (score 0):

Once the client side has successfully cleared your authentication challenge, the server can issue a token to the caller on the client side.  In subsequent calls to the server, the client would send the token as one of the arguments and the server would verify the token and respond accordingly.

The token can contain a segment of information that identifies a given user, and implementing this will provide the functionality you are seeking.

The only guidelines for generating tokens is that they are unique, non-predictable and expirable.  I have always encrypted my tokens so that they appear as gibberish, but step this is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I've also done very much "googleing" and got a lot of headache before I got the solution.
I don't use RIA-Services - but it should be (hopefully) the same...:

The SL-Client sends a "login-request" to the server.

On the (WCF) server-side, I do the following (LoginData = Return-Info for SL-Client):

```
public LoginData LoginRequest() {
    (...)
    OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties prp = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endPrp = prp[System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        (...)
        try {
            clientIP = endPrp.Address;
            System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(clientIP);
            System.Net.IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        (...)
```

If you want to check the users WindowsPrincipal, you can do the following (securityGroup = server-side setting, which users can login):

```
    (...)
    switch (securityGroup) {
            case SecurityGroup.AllClientsCanAccess: {
                clientCanLogin = true;
            } break;
            case SecurityGroup.UseWindowsCredentials: {
                if (OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext != null && OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity != null) {
                        if (OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.IsAuthenticated) {

                            if (subSecurityInfo1 == true) { // only clients in specific roles can log in
                                bool userRoleFound = false;

                                WindowsPrincipal userPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity);
                                if (userPrincipal == null)
                                    break;

                                foreach (string userRoleToPass in subSecurityList) {    // subSecurityList = settings, which roles can pass

                                    loginError.ErrorInfo += string.Format("{0}\n", userRoleToPass);

                                    if (userPrincipal.IsInRole(userRoleToPass)) {
                                        clientCanLogin = userRoleFound = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (userRoleFound) {
                                    loginError.ErrorInfo = string.Empty;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else {
                                    loginError.ErrorNo = LoginErrorCodeNoEnum.UserIsNotInRole;
                                }
                            }
                            (...)
```

Hope it helps...